# Add custom block/div Order Details page

Tags: module, admin, ce-1.7.0.2, sales

I have a custom module, whose content I need to show on Order Details page.

Not under any new tab or something but just above the "Order Totals" div.

How do I accomplish this without modifying any core files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add layout file in yourmagento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourmodule.xml

Add below content in that:

```
  <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourmodule/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml</template>
        </action> 
<!-- Add your block to display in above order total block -->
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Copy default info.phtml file from app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/yourmodule/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml

Add your content in info.phtml as per your need above order total div.

Comment: "<!-- Add your block to display in above order total block -->" I am sorry to ask but in what way I should  add the block?

Comment: here you can add block which you wanted to display above order total, eg.:  <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml"></block>

above block is added to show order history using <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_history') ?> in info.phtml

I hope you can understand what i am trying to say :)

Comment: Yes followed you but getting this error:   Invalid method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info::shouldDisplayCustomerIp(Array
(
)
)

Comment: have you extend your custom block with Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info class?

Answer (score 6):

To add the contents to the Order Information section (First block on the admin order page), inside app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourmodule.xml add below:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourmodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Now you can copy:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/yourmodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

Now you can add your stuff to the info.phtml inside your module, without change the core files.

Comment: The problem on this approach is conflicting with other modules that already override this file.