# Add custom view on magento admin order view page

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, orders

Want to add my custom info block on magento admin order view page using my custom plugin. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are your trying to add a "tab" or just add info to an existing "tab"? Please provide more info or add a markup image.

Comment: Yes i want to add my custom info in existing 'information' tab.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with some "top name" magento extension, this is how they do it

Create a block to display the info then edit

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

and add

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('magepal/adminhtml_blockname')
          ->toHtml();
```

Also see [Add custom block/div Order Details page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13455/add-custom-block-div-order-details-page)

Comment: Problem is to add our custom block without touching core blocks or files. can you please let me know how should i  add my block in this case?

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13455/add-custom-block-div-order-details-page

Comment: I already had a look here. in this case I need to copy all the customer info code from core file to my custom phtml file with my additional info. I do not want to copy any existing code in my custom phtml. I just want to add only my custom info to my phtml and want it to dispaly after customer info or order info or anywhere in order view page. Let me know if i am still unclear.

Comment: From my experience with customizing magento admin section, it's not a flexible as the front-end. I have seen several well known magento extension done it this way and I dont think it can be done any other 'cleaner' way